# analyzing height of b-tree

Tags: tree, b-tree

I am reading about B-trees at following location

http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/

Here author is analyzing B-tree height.

The minimum number of keys in a B-tree of order M >= 2 and height  is >= 0 is Nk = 2 * ceiling (M/2) ^ h -1

:Proof Clearly, a B-tree of height zero contains at least one node. Consider a B-tree order M and height h>0. By Definition each internal node (except the root) has at least ceiling (M/2) subtrees. This implies the minimum number of keys contained in an internal node is celing (M/2)-1. The minimum number of keys a level zero is 1; at level one, 2(celing(M/2)-1) ;, at level two 2(ceiling (m/2)(Ceiling(M/2)-1)

My question is how author concluded that level 1 minimum number of kesy are 2(celing(M/2)-1) and for level 2?

for example if M is 2 then minimum number of keys at level1 is coming as 0, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Look Man,no of keys at level 1 will be minimum when root node has two subtrees.So at level one we have two nodes.Therefore minimum number of keys at level 1 = 2(celing(M/2)-1).Now considering level 2.As

1)There are 2(ceiling (m/2)) subtrees(minimum) for nodes at level 1.

2)there the minimum no of keys at level 2 is 2(ceiling (m/2))*(ceiling(m/2) -1).

Just read the basics if you still don't get it.